# Capture the last occurrence of a tag

Tags: python, regex, xml

My text is of the form:

```
<Story>
 <Sentence id="1"> some text </Sentence>   
 <Sentence id="2"> some text </Sentence>   
 <Sentence id="3"> some text </Sentence>
```

My task is to insert a closing tag `</Story>` after the last `</Sentence>`. In the text, every `</Sentence>` is followed by 3 spaces. I tried capturing the last `</Sentence>` using the regex `</Sentence>(?!.*<Sentence)` and used re.DOTALL too. But its not working.

Actual code used is 
 
`line = re.sub(re.compile('</Sentence>(?!.*<Sentence)',re.DOTALL),'</Sentence></Story>',line)`

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You really should [use a parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for this.

Comment: @David @msw Use a parser for invalid xml? Don't parsers throw exceptions on seeing non well-formed xml docs?

Comment: good point, some do, but some would be able to recognize a missing tag and add it automatically. I guess it depends on the context. And even so, when a parser throws an exception it might contain the position of the invalid tag, which would be the place to insert the `</Story>` tag.

Comment: Both HTML Tidy and BeautifulSoup are specifically designed to cope with malformed markup.

Comment: Parsing XML with Regex sounds nice and easy, but it shouldn't be done unless the gains from using Regex outweigh the negatives of not using a library.

Comment: like that it's not XML it is however valid SGML perhaps an SGML parser can be used.

Answer (score 3):

Is the same code producing the whole file - if so then use an xml library to generate it then all tags will be nested correctly - if not fix the code producing it so that it is valid XML.

regexes and xml do not go together well.

Comment: The code that I am using generates a bunch of Sentence tags. I am trying to simply put a root tag around so that it becomes a valid xml. Placing the `<Story` tag was no bid deal. I am stuck with its closing tag.

Comment: @afs: some reason you can't use `'<Story>' + sentences + '</Story>'`?

Answer (score 1):

You really should use a parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to do the job. BeautifulSoup can parse very incorrect HTML/XML and tries to make them look correct. Your code could look like this (I'm assuming you have some tags before and after your incorrect `Story` tag, or else you would follow the advice from David's comment):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup

html = '''
<Document>
<PrevTag></PrevTag>
<Story>
 <Sentence id="1"> some text </Sentence>   
 <Sentence id="2"> some text </Sentence>   
 <Sentence id="3"> some text </Sentence>
<EndTag></EndTag>
</Document> 
'''
# Parse the document:
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(html)
```

Look how BeautifulSoup parsed it:

```
print soup.prettify()

#<document>
# <prevtag>
# </prevtag>
# <story>
#  <sentence id="1">
#   some text
#  </sentence>
#  <sentence id="2">
#   some text
#  </sentence>
#  <sentence id="3">
#   some text
#  </sentence>
#  <endtag>
#  </endtag>
# </story>
#</document>
```

Notice that BeautifulSoup closed the Story right before the closing of the tag that surrounded it (Document), so you have to move the closing tag next to the last sentence.

```
# Find the last sentence:
last_sentence = soup.findAll('sentence')[-1]

# Find the Story tag:
story = soup.find('story')

# Move all tags after the last sentence outside the Story tag:
sib = last_sentence.nextSibling
while sib:
    story.parent.append(sib.extract())
    sib = last_sentence.nextSibling

print soup.prettify()

#<document>
# <prevtag>
# </prevtag>
# <story>
#  <sentence id="1">
#   some text
#  </sentence>
#  <sentence id="2">
#   some text
#  </sentence>
#  <sentence id="3">
#   some text
#  </sentence>
# </story>
# <endtag>
# </endtag>
#</document>
```

The end result should be exactly what you wanted. Note that this code assumes there is only one Story in the document -- if not, it should be modified slightly. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to find the last occurrence of the tag, you can:

```
reSentenceClose= re.compile('</Sentence> *')
match= None
for match in reSentenceClose.finditer(your_text):
    pass

if match: # it was found
    print match.end() # the index in your_text where the pattern was found
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not match all three (or however many) `<Sentence>` elements and plug them back in with a group reference?

```
re.sub(r'(?:(\r?\n) *<Sentence.*?</Sentence> *)+',
       r'$0$1</Story>',
       line)
```